# Definition of Powers in Stromberg's Introduction to Classical Real Analysis

Tags: real-analysis, complex-numbers, exponentiation, real-numbers

On pages 136-137 of his book *Introduction to Classical Real Analysis* Stromberg makes the following definition:

[image]

Am having qualms about his definition $0^b=0$ for any complex number $b\neq 0$, which doesn't seem to agree with usual conventions (e.g. $0^{-1}$ is usually undefined). Is this a mistake? Or is there a reason for making such an extended definition?

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: I can't confidently say it's a mistake, but I have to say I can't see how it could be of much use, because it implies $0^{1+(-1)} = 0^0 = 1 \ne 0 = 00 = 0^10^{-1},$ so it is false that $0^{b+c} = 0^b0^c$ for all complex $b, c.$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You (and Calum Gilhooley) are right to be dubious about this. For $z=x+\mathrm iy\in\Bbb C$, with $x,y\in\Bbb R$, it is problematic to assign any meaning to $0^z$ unless $x>0$ or $x=y=0$. It would be interesting to know whether Stromberg actually makes use of his “definition” of $0^z$ in the cases $x<0$ or $x=0$ with $y\neq0$.

Comment: I read until page 257 of the book and Stromberg didn't use this convention yet. There are very few typos in the book so am genuinely puzzled by this definition...

Comment: @Alphie : This is probably an oversight rather than a typo. Stromberg has nothing to gain by this overextension of the definition of $a^b$

Comment: Ok I thought he meant $b>0  (b\in\mathbb{R})$ instead of $b\neq0$, because earlier in the book he defined $0^b=0$ for all real numbers $b>0$. So you think it is better to leave $0^b$ undefined in other cases? (except for the special case $0^0=1$)

Comment: Yes, certainly. If you allow $0^{-1}=0$, then you have to make an asymmetrical exception to the identity $z^{-1}\equiv1/z$: namely that the LHS is zero but the RHS is undefined when $z=0$. Why would anyone want to do that?